# How to detect a rightclick in an application

Tags: c#, right-click

my objective is to attach a context menu (vista and win7) whenever user right clicks a picture/file.

I've got the file portion down (ie, they right click on a file and my menu shows up) but I am having trouble understanding what I would need to do in terms of right clicking in firefox or ie .

I am trying to add a context menu whenever someone right clicks on an image file in IE or firefox. is that possible?

Comment: This might be more of a registry hack than C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to develop a plug-in for the browser used by your user, whether it be for Internet Explorer, FireFox or Chrome etc..

Trying to create some sort of hack will only lead to a bad experience for your user so it's better to develop something that would work properly.

Here's a few links to get you going in the right direction:

Google Chrome: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/write-chrome-extension/

Mozilla FireFox: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview/)

(I can't seem to find any for Internet Explorer)

I'm sorry i cannot give you a definitive answer but hopefully this should get the ball rolling for you at least.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to plug in to what happens inside the user's browser, you should probably write a browser extension to do that, instead of trying to hack up something awful that sort of does what you want maybe.

Answer (score 0):

is that possible?

NO

For Browsers: You need to develop an extension for each browser you want to support

For Desktop: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dateparser.aspx (ignore all the stupid istruction about how to catch the datetime )